# Convert object to enum C#

Tags: c#, silverlight, windows-phone-7

I have binded a list of enum to a combobox. Now I want to get the `SelectedItem` return the enum, which currently returns it as type `object`. How do I convert this object to my enum?

My framework is silverlight on windows-phone-7

Answer (score 29, accepted):

Cast it directly:

```
MyEnum selected = (MyEnum)cboCombo.SelectedItem;
```

Note that you can't use the `as` cast in this case since an `Enum` is a value type.

Comment: wow, this works now. For some reason, the compiler was telling me that `MyEnum` is being used as a variable in that exact statement.

Comment: @Jon Seigel good call on the "as" cast comment.  Does Visual Studio do "unboxing" behind the scenes here?

Answer (score 6):

Have you tried this??

```
YourEnum abc = (YourEnum) Enum.Parse(typeof(YourEnum), yourObject.ToString());
```

Comment: That may work with a string property, but not with `SelectedItem`.

Comment: @leppie: I thought, for some reason, typecasting is not working for OP, so he can try this trick.